Was the "demon core" hot?
The demon core was a sphere of plutonium (Pu-239, not Pu-238 that is known to get hot and is used in RTG) that weighed 6.2 kilograms (14 lb) and was 8.9 centimeters (3.5 in) in diameter. It was made with small safety margin and could go prompt-critical but most of the time, it was not.
I have heard the claim that the core was hot to touch due nuclear decay producing the heat. Would such a plutonium sphere feel hot if touched by a human?
This maybe could be calculated rather than looking for historical references. If through historical references, also OK but then please include them in your answer.

The Trinity core was described as being warm to the touch.

Would it be safe to be near a core that is warm to the touch?

There were accidents during experiments but researchers worked that close to it.

@mmesser314 - the primary (by a huge margin) non-critical decay path of Pu-239 is by alpha emission, so actually pretty safe (particularly for those days).

"Hot" is not meant to be taken literally. In the relevant domain's slang, "hot" means "highly radioactive", not necessarily "high temperature".

Dad was a foundry man; his answer'd'be no. Not if you can stand in front of it and hold it open with a flathead screwdriver without wearing an aluminized suit.

A simple way to estimate this would be to check reference decay heating powers for the isotopes. From here we can find a value of $1.9~\mathrm{W}\,\mathrm{kg}^{-1}$ for plutonium-239. For a sphere with a mass of $6.2~\mathrm{kg}$, this leads to an estimated heat production of about $12~\mathrm{W}$.
A 6.2-kg sphere of plutonium will have a surface area of about $223~\mathrm{cm}^2$. At $20\,^\circ\mathrm{C}$, such an object (assuming emissivity 1) will radiate roughly $9~\mathrm{W}$ (via the Stefan-Boltzmann law). Add the excess heat from decay to get a total equilibrium radiated power of about $21~\mathrm{W}$, which again by the Stefan-Boltzmann law corresponds to a temperature of around 37 $87~^\circ\mathrm{C}$ if we take an ambient temperature of $20~^\circ\mathrm{C}$ (which we already did implicitly by using that to find the original radiated power).
If we also incorporate convective cooling of the form $P=hA\Delta T$, with an assumed heat transfer coefficient of $h=10~\mathrm{W}\,\mathrm{m}^{-2}\,\mathrm{K}^{-1}$, then I find a new equilibrium temperature of about $50~^\circ\mathrm{C}$.
I'm not sure if that counts as hot, but it certainly counts as at least warm!

Wouldn't air convection be a significant, if not dominant, cooling mechanism in these circumstances? So probably even cooler than 37 degrees?

@jkej Is it windy? Humid? How conducting/insulating is its stand, and how much of the sphere is covered by the stand? This calculation is much smaller than the back of an envelope with 1 significant figure. I'm not what temperatures are tepid warm and hot, but I think there's enough here to say that the sphere would be warm.

Pu-239 (esp. early weapon-grade samples) is usually contaminated with considerable amount of Pu-238. Pu-238 decay heat is much more and is also a known engineering limitation in bomb designs.

@jkej Sorry, I made a sign error in original calc - really ~87 C. I've tried incorporating a simple model for convective cooling, as well

@user121330 I didn't claim to know the answer and it's certainly possible that the sphere would be warm. I was just a little bit sceptical that radiative cooling would be so dominant in this situation since I know it typically isn't for other comparable situations.

I have not done historical analysis on the actual demon core itself, or whether anyone who touched it managed to describe it as “hot” before expiring.
However, from a physics standpoint, I would anticipate a nearly-critical mass of fissile material to be hot. A nuclear explosion is simply a block of critical fissile material getting really hot very fast; when a fissile object is very close to criticality, the rate of nuclear reactions is not quite enough to be self-sustaining, but those reactions still produce significant heat, more heat the closer the reaction is to criticality.
I would imagine that something like the demon core, which could ascend to criticality just by putting a lid on it, would be producing a large amount of heat and would be hot to the touch.

Fissionable materials display strongly non-linear behavior.  A subcritical quantity, regardless of how close to critical it is, will be heated mostly by spontaneous fission, not by neutron-induced fission.  It's only once you go supercritical that you get the exponentially-growing chain reaction that produces "really hot very fast".
